# UWP Windows app Certification kit Error 0x80070057: Windows cannot create the AppContainer Profile for the xxxxx Package

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal

I want to change the app name on windows store, here is what I have done:

1. Reserved a new name using windows developer dashboard
2. Changed *Diplay Name* of Package.appxmanifest on Application Tab
3. Changed *Package Dispaly Name* of Package.appmanifest on Packaging Tab
4. Associate app with the store
5. Create app package successfully

But when I launch the app certification kit it always shows error 0x80070057: Windows cannot create the AppContainer Profile for the xxxxx Package. I am using windows app certification kit version 10.0.16299.15. Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since your app has been in the Store, you might update **Package.StoreAssociation.xml** before modify `DisplayName` in package.manifest. See the `Important` note in **[Rename an app that has already been published](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-app-names#rename-an-app-that-has-already-been-published)**:

> Be sure to update the Package.StoreAssociation.xml file before you change the **Package/Properties/DisplayName** in the app manifest, or you may get an error.

Comment: Thank you @Zhendong, In my case there was problem on app name because I had | symbol on my app which is not allowed, [link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).